what's wrong with reversing array?
I will be given an array. It can be sorted or unsorted. If it is unsorted, my task is to check if I can swap two integers that make the array sorted.
I read the array then I check if the array is sorted or not. If it's not, I made two integers. The first checks the number which made the problem from the first, and the second integer checks the number which made the problem from the end of the array, then I reversed the sub array from the index of the first integer to the index of the second integer.
But, there is something wrong in my code. Denote the size of the array(n) which (1<=n<=10^5), and the time limit for this problem is 1 second. Which does not allow me to use inner loops. And the array is 1-based.
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int n , array[100010] = {} , start=1 , end=1;

   std::cin >>n; // read the size of the array

   for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)
   {
       std::cin>>array[i]; // read the array
   }

   for(int i=1 ; i<n ; i++)
   {
       if(array[i] > array[i+1] ) //check if it's sorted from the first
       {
           start = i; // the index of the number which is not ordered in ascending order
           break;
       }
   }

   for(int i=n ; i>1 ; i--)
   {
       if(array[i] < array[i-1] ) // check if it's sorted from the end
       {
           end = i;// the index of the number which is not ordered in ascending order
           break;
       }
   }

   if(start == end) // check if it's sorted
   {
       std::cout << "yes\n" << array[start] << ' ' << array[start];

       return 0;
   }

   for(int i=0 ; i<=(end-start-1) ; i++) // reverse the sub array which has wrong order
   {
       std::swap(array[i+start] , array[end-i]);
   }

   for(int i=1 ; i<n ; i++)//check if the array is sorted after reversing
   {
       if(array[i] > array[i+1])
       {
           std::cout<<"no";
           return 0;
       }
   }

   std::cout << "yes\n" << array[start] << ' ' << array[end];
}


To begin with, use zero-based indexing like everyone else is doing. Secondly, start small, do one thing and do it well before you continue with the next part of the assignment.

As for your assignment, why does the array need to be sorted? What is the actual assignment or exercise? Please [edit] your question to tell us, and remember to include all requirements and limitations.

"check If I can swap two integers that make the array sorted" Swapping two elements is not the same as reversing a sub-array!

Time-limited challenges usually contains a "trick" - something you should realize to be able to solve it. Here it might be that you don't have to store the array to just check the ordering - you only need 2 or 3 numbers at a time to see if they are sorted.

The problem with your code is that your loop goes through the entire region of the array that needs reversing. If you do that everything gets swapped twice and you end up with the same order you started with. You need to swap the first half of the region with the second half of the region.

Given what I believe your assignment states, you don't need any hand-coded for loops.
See std::is_sorted_until and std::sort.  For example, this entire loop: for(int i=1 ; i<n ; i++) { if(array[i] > array[i+1] )  { start = i;  break; }}  is start = *std::is_sorted_until(array, array + n); (if you actually use zero-based indexing).

for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)    {     std::cin>>array[i]; // read the array    } why do you skip array[0]? Remember that in c++ arrays are indexed 0 .. size - 1

Search the internet for "C++ bubble sort tutorial".  See if there are any similarities to what you assignment is.

StackOverflow is a Q&A site for specific technical question, not a homework service. Please read How do I ask and answer homework questions? and Open letter to students with homework problems

Your question can be improved by including data from a sample run, with (1) input data, and (2) expected output.

Several comments recommend switching to zero-based arrays. But the OP explicitly states: "the array is 1-based." Is it possible that you have misunderstood the problem specification? I doubt that it is intended that you use one-based subscripting.

"there is something wrong in my code" -- What makes you say that? (What is the symptom?)

You don't need to store entire array in memory, you can analyze incoming data in one pass "on the fly".
